# Creating dynamic web project with maven in eclipse and deployable with oracle weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, eclipse-wtp, weblogic12c

I want to create a project which contains a parent pom.xml with different common dependencies (Like Spring, JDBC, Log4j etc.) and it can be deployed on weblogic so that I can access the web-services following Project Configuration.

1. Main Project (Deployed on Oracle Weblogic) .
   pom.xml (Parent Pom containing all following modules in it)
2. Module 1
   pom.xml
3. Module 2
   pom.xml

What should be the starting point and configurations, while i am using the following way to create this.

1. Have created Main Project with packing type pom (For creating Module based maven project).
2. Module 1 with packing type WAR.
3. Module 2 with packing type WAR.

Then how can i deploy the main project in web-logic to make deployment simple.

Thanks In advance, Although I am figuring out the ways to complete this task parallelly but all other help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your local machine you could use the **Oracle Weblogic Server Tools**: Open the servers view in Eclipse and click the link to download more server integrations than there are by default. Select the Oracle Weblogic Tools of the same version that your Weblogic Server.
You can the add a Web-Project (or EAR-project) to your server.

If you want to deploy to a remote weblogic server have a look at the **Oracle Weblogic Maven Plugin** that comes with the Weblogic installation.